# Making a Unique Indicator Column in Pandas Based off of Two Columns

Tags: python, pandas

This has been a tricky one for me. So my data structure is roughly the following:

| column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | a |
| 111 | a |
| 111 | a |
| 111 | a |
| 111 | b |
| 111 | b |
| 222 | a |
| 222 | b |
| 222 | b |
| 222 | b |
| 222 | b |
| 222 | b |

I want to get to this in the most efficient way possible from a processing perspective:

| column_1 | column_2 | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | a | 1 |
| 111 | a | 2 |
| 111 | a | 3 |
| 111 | a | 4 |
| 111 | b | 1 |
| 111 | b | 2 |
| 222 | a | 1 |
| 222 | b | 1 |
| 222 | b | 2 |
| 222 | b | 3 |
| 222 | b | 4 |
| 222 | b | 5 |

In summary I want to create a column that will turn each row into a unique occurrence. The preference is that this `unique_id` column starts at `1` for each new combination of `column_1` and `column_2`.

Comment: ``df.assign(unique_id = df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2']).cumcount() + 1``

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I was going down the path of iterating and using `apply` this is so much better